Excel Validation formulas addition in Apache POI for different cells have incorrect relative reference
I am using Apache POI to apply different formulas to different cells in same column.
Example to explain the issue



Column 1
Column 2




1st Type
row


2nd Type
row


1st Type
row



For 1st and 3rd row, column 2 has dataValidaton rule 1 and for 2nd row, column 2 has data validation rule 2.
I am seeing an inconsistent experience where for some rows correct row reference is getting calculated, while for other not.
Actual issue logs

Applying data validation rule: AND(OR(N3="", M3<>""), OR(M3="", AND(AND(ISNUMBER(M3), M3>=0, M3=ROUND(M3, 2)), OR(M3="", J3="", J3<M3)))) to header: HeaderName and address list: [org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [M3:M3], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [M4:M4], ..., org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [M1296:M1296]


Applying data validation rule: OR(M3="", AND(AND(ISNUMBER(M3), M3>=0, M3=ROUND(M3, 2)), OR(M3="", J3="", J3<M3))) to header: HeaderName and address list: [org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [M7:M7], org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress [M84:M84]

The relative replacement is working fine at some places while not at others:
In reality,

M3 formula is: =AND(OR(N3="", M3<>""), OR(M3="", AND(AND(ISNUMBER(M3), M3>=0, M3=ROUND(M3, 2)), OR(M3="", J3="", J3<M3))))
M1296 formula is: =AND(OR(N1296="", M1296<>""), OR(M1296="", AND(AND(ISNUMBER(M1296), M1296>=0, M1296=ROUND(M1296, 2)), OR(M1296="", J1296="", J1296<M1296))))

However,

M7 formula is: =OR(M3="", AND(AND(ISNUMBER(M3), M3>=0, M3=ROUND(M3, 2)), OR(M3="", J3="", J3<M3)))
M84 formula is: =OR(M80="", AND(AND(ISNUMBER(M80), M80>=0, M80=ROUND(M80, 2)), OR(M80="", J80="", J80<M80)))

